# List comparisons with specific comparison criteria?

Tags: c#, .net

I have the following 3 classes:

```
public class RuleSet
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int SiteId { get; set; }

    public List<RuleInstance> RuleInstances { get; set; }

    public RuleSetType RuleSetType { get; set; } // RuleSetType is an ENUM
}

public class RuleInstance
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int RuleSetId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("RuleSetId")]
    public RuleSet RuleSet { get; set; }

    public int RuleId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("RuleId")]
    public Rule Rule { get; set; }

    public string RuleValue { get; set; }

    public Guid RuleGroupId { get; set; }
}

public class Rule
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ModuleType ModuleType { get; set; } // ModuleType is an ENUM
}
```

I have a query that returns a list of all `RuleSets` (with related `RuleInstances` & `Rules`) for a specific `SiteId` and `RuleSetType`.

My first list of `RuleSets` is for `RuleSetType` 'Foo' and my second list of `RuleSets` is for `RuleSetType` 'Bar' (for the same SiteId).

What I'd like to do is be able to compare these 2 Lists, and identify any `RuleSets` that appear in both lists, but the comparison needs to be based only on certain properties within each RuleSets objects.

The key criteria that I want to be able to use in the comparison would be:

**Must Match**

- RuleSet.RuleInstance(s).RuleId
- RuleSet.RuleInstance(s).RuleValue

**Ignore (as they won't ever be the same)**

- RuleSet.Id
- RuleSet.RuleSetType
- RuleSet.RuleInstance(s).Id
- RuleSet.RuleInstance(s).RuleSetId
- RuleSet.RuleInstance(s).RuleGroupId

Ultimately, I'd then like to end up with some sort of collection that contains each matching pair of RuleSets (albeit 'matching' based on the 'Must Match' properties highlighted above), so I can then look at each pairing in turn, and based on some other business logic, I can decide which of those 2 RuleSets I actually want to use.

Comment: Use a HashSet and override equals for RuleInstance.

Comment: Please see the marked duplicate for an example of how to use `IEqualityComparer<T>` with LINQ methods. In your case, it sounds like the [`Intersect()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb355408(v=vs.110).aspx) method instead of `SequenceEqual()`, but the basic idea is the same.